# Cannot revert sound output back after using HDMI[14.04]

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I used HDMI to my TV with success, outputting both sound and picture.

After unplugging the HDMI from my desktop PC, however the audio persists outputting to "HDMI / Displayport", if I toggle +/- for sound.

How do I revert it back to the original audio output?

I have attempted rebooting with the HDMI not plugged in. It did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the default Ubuntu desktop (Unity):

1. Click on the speaker icon near the right edge of the bar at the top of the screen.
2. When the menu appears, select "Sound Settings".

If you're using any other desktop, open an xterm and type the command

`unity-control-center sound`

In either case: A window will pop up on the screen, and you'll see "Play Sound Through:".  You can select either HDMI or "Analog Output, Built-In Audio"; that last one is the one you want.

You can then click on "Test sound" to make sure sound is now going where you want it to go.

Comment: I use Gnome 3 desktop environment. How would I go about that in this case?

Comment: @cbll: At least for the sake of this change, I'd login using the default Ubuntu desktop.  (I actually run fvwm, but start up the default only when I need to deal with sound, since I don't otherwise know how to start up the utility that controls sound.)

Comment: @cbll: OK, try opening an xterm and giving the command "unity-control-center sound"; that works under fvwm, and gets you the same box you need to change where the sound goes.  (Just discovered by analyzing the output of "ps x" both with and without that utility running.)

Comment: Appreciate it, `unity-control-center sound` brings out the option and I can choose analogue output and it changes instantly